# Initialize IdentityUser using the Entity Framework initializer

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, code-first

As the password is encrypted, How can I initialize a user using the Seed method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize a Usermanager object and create user.

```
protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
     var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
     var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
     var admin = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "your username", Email = "your email" };
     userManager.Create(admin, "your password");
}
```

Comment: It doesn't resolve the problem. Because the password you provide is encrypted. And when I want to login with the provided. It's not recognized thanks. Any Idea ?

Comment: It works for me. The password that you set on create method is the password not the hash. what is the error you are getting when you try to login?